# Is having a reference/ptr to std::unique_ptr<> owned object safe when the unique_ptr is in a vector?

Tags: c++

On the surface I like the pattern of having a container of `unique_ptr`'s to own data. My question is, is it safe to then take pointers/references to members of such an owned object, if I know that the `unique_ptr` will not go out of scope?

For example I may have

```
auto v = std::vector<std::unique_ptr<ClassWithFooMember>>{};
v.emplace_back(std::make_unique<ClassWithFooMember>());
```

Can I then safely do

```
auto *foo_ptr = &(v.at(0)->foo);
```

if I know that `v` will outlive `foo_ptr` and that `v` will never have an item removed?

What happens if many items are added to `v` or if `v`'s internal representation changes? Will the memory layouts of the `ClassWithFooMember` instances ever change?

Thank you.

Comment: If you would have written `ClassWithFooMember *foo_ptr` or given the definition of `ClassWithFooMember`, you would probably have avoided to accept an incorrect answer from someone who read the question a bit too fast.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the `ClassWithFooMember` objects “in” such a `vector` are allocated **separately**, your `foo_ptr` (or a pointer to the *entire* `ClassWithFooMember` object) will remain valid regardless of *any* operations on `v` so long as the (anonymous) `ClassWithFooMember` object exists.  For instance, sorting `v` or causing it to reallocate would be harmless. `v.erase(v.begin())` would destroy it, of course, but even then you might first have written either of

```
auto p=std::move(v.front());
auto *q=v.front().release();
```

which would let the object live on after **destroying** `v` entirely.

All this is true regardless of the **container type**; this is the benefit paid for by the additional memory and time **overhead** used for the separate allocation.  Neither is it specific to `std::unique_ptr` (although that’s generally a good choice here for other reasons); `std::vector<T*>` would have the same behavior, including that it would be safe to retain a `T*` (or a pointer *into* a `T`) but not a `T*&` (or `T**`) referring to the `vector` element **itself**.  (The corresponding *unsafe* thing in your case would be to hold a `std::unique_ptr<ClassWithFooMember>&` or `std::unique_ptr<ClassWithFooMember>*`, which you generally shouldn’t be doing anyway.)

Comment: That's what I was hoping, but what you say contrasts @Konrads answer. As such I still don't know who to believe :)